# Unable to scrape the names from json response

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping

There are around 966 names in the webpage with json content but with my script I'm getting only 10 out of them. I'm very new to json that is why I'can't figure out the mistake I'm making. How can I get all the names? I'm trying with the below code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.zebra.com/bin/zebra/partnersearch?inMiles=true&start=0&numRows=10&latitude=39.5500507&longitude=-105.7820674&sortOrder=asc&sortBy=distance&country=US&searchRadius=5000'

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
for item in data:
    print(item['name'])
```

Partial json content from that page is:

```
[{"id":"001i000001XR9dqAAD","website":"www.resortinternet.com","type":"partner","phoneNumber":"+1.970.262.3515","name":"Resortnet, LLC","logoPresent":"No","logoExtension":"","des":"Technology provider for destination resorts","translatedName":"ResortInternet","dbaName":"ResortInternet","PR":"NA","AN":"6244306","accountType":["Reseller"],"contentType":"parent","countries":["US"],"HSA":[],"countriesAndHsa":["US"],"premierSolutionPartner":false,"premierBusinessPartner":false,"solutionPartner":true,"businessPartner":false,"advancedSpecialistBarcodePrinterSupplies":false,"advancedSpecialistCardPrinters":false,"advancedSpecialistSupplies":false,"advancedSpecialistWirelessNetworks":false,"advancedSpecialistPrintEngines":false,"advancedSpecialistRfid":false,"specialistBarcodePrinterSupplies":false,"specialistCardPrinters":false,"specialistSupplies":false,"specialistWirelessNetworks":false,"specialistPrintEngines":false,"specialistRfid":false,"advancedRepairSpecialistLabelPrinter":false,"advancedRepairSpecialistCardPrinter":false,"advancedRepairSpecialistMobilePrinter":false,"advancedRepairSpecialistPrintEngine":false,"repairSpecialistLabelPrinter":false,"repairSpecialistCardPrinter":false,"repairSpecialistMobilePrinter":false,"repairSpecialistPrintEngine":false,"registeredResellerNoSpecialization":false,"pmiWraps":[{"programName":"Solution Partner","category":"Reseller","id":"001i000001XR9dqAAD_2","type":"pmiWrap","contentType":"child"}],"partnerLocations":[{"locationType":"Headquarters","addressLine1":"117 S 6th Ave.,","addressLine2":"PO Box 2718","city":"Frisco","state":"Colorado","zipCode":"80443","country":"United States","phone":"(970) 262-3515","fax":"(970) 668-9431","latlon":"39.5754576,-106.0952117","distance":16.8,"countryCode":"US","HSA":[],"id":"001i000001XR9dqAAD_0","type":"partnerLocation","contentType":"child"},{"locationType":"Primary Location","addressLine1":"117 S 6th Ave.,","city":"Frisco","state":"Colorado","zipCode":"80443","country":"United States","phone":"+1.970.262.3515","latlon":"39.5754576,-106.0952117","distance":16.8,"countryCode":"US","HSA":[],"id":"001i000001XR9dqAAD_1","type":"partnerLocation","contentType":"child"},{"locationType":"Address","addressLine1":"RESORTINTERNET\r2718:FRISCO:80443\r117 S 6TH AVERM UNIT 2","city":"Frisco","state":"Colorado","stateCode":"CO","zipCode":"80443","country":"United States","latlon":"39.5744309,-106.0975203","distance":16.9,"countryCode":"US","HSA":[],"id":"001i000001XR9dqAAD_100","type":"partnerLocation","contentType":"child"}],"verticalHierarchyWraps":[],"primaryLocation":{"locationType":"Headquarters","addressLine1":"117 S 6th Ave.,","addressLine2":"PO Box 2718","city":"Frisco","state":"Colorado","zipCode":"80443","country":"United States","phone":"(970) 262-3515","fax":"(970) 668-9431","latlon":"39.5754576,-106.0952117","distance":16.8,"countryCode":"US","HSA":
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a problem with your code. If you check `len(data)` it returns `10`, which means that the list of results contains only 10 (large) JSON objects.

Is there some reason you're expecting more than 10, or are you trying to access the `name` property of something inside each of these larger objects?

Comment: Thanks Emersonct, for your answer. I checked the length as well. Now it makes more sense to me as a starter. At this point I should think of selenium, I suppose.

Comment: @SMth80: You actually shouldn't need to do that to get more results. Notice that in the url you're using there is the querystring argument: `&numRows=10`. Changing that to a larger number (or removing it?) should help.

Comment: If even that isn't enough, I think you can loop through all results by incrementing the `start` query parameter by the `numRows` amount each call until no more results are returned.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is an array of objects, so when you loop through the data you aren't getting the array in your `item` variable but instead are getting the index of the array.

You can get the array by using the item variable as the index and once you have a reference to the array you can then read property objects such as name:

Like this:

```
for index in data:
    item = data[index]
    print(item['name'])
```

Here it is in JavaScript:

```html
<script>
var data = [
   {
      "id":"001i000001XR9dqAAD",
      "website":"www.resortinternet.com",
      "type":"partner",
      "phoneNumber":"+1.970.262.3515",
      "name":"Resortnet, LLC",
      "logoPresent":"No",
      "logoExtension":"",
      "des":"Technology provider for destination resorts",
      "translatedName":"ResortInternet",
      "dbaName":"ResortInternet",
      "PR":"NA",
      "AN":"6244306",
      "accountType":[
         "Reseller"
      ],
      "contentType":"parent",
      "countries":[
         "US"
      ],
      "HSA":[

      ],
      "countriesAndHsa":[
         "US"
      ],
      "premierSolutionPartner":false,
      "premierBusinessPartner":false,
      "solutionPartner":true,
      "businessPartner":false,
      "advancedSpecialistBarcodePrinterSupplies":false,
      "advancedSpecialistCardPrinters":false,
      "advancedSpecialistSupplies":false,
      "advancedSpecialistWirelessNetworks":false,
      "advancedSpecialistPrintEngines":false,
      "advancedSpecialistRfid":false,
      "specialistBarcodePrinterSupplies":false,
      "specialistCardPrinters":false,
      "specialistSupplies":false,
      "specialistWirelessNetworks":false,
      "specialistPrintEngines":false,
      "specialistRfid":false,
      "advancedRepairSpecialistLabelPrinter":false,
      "advancedRepairSpecialistCardPrinter":false,
      "advancedRepairSpecialistMobilePrinter":false,
      "advancedRepairSpecialistPrintEngine":false,
      "repairSpecialistLabelPrinter":false,
      "repairSpecialistCardPrinter":false,
      "repairSpecialistMobilePrinter":false,
      "repairSpecialistPrintEngine":false,
      "registeredResellerNoSpecialization":false,
      "pmiWraps":[
         {
            "programName":"Solution Partner",
            "category":"Reseller",
            "id":"001i000001XR9dqAAD_2",
            "type":"pmiWrap",
            "contentType":"child"
         }
      ],
      "partnerLocations":[
         {
            "locationType":"Headquarters",
            "addressLine1":"117 S 6th Ave.,",
            "addressLine2":"PO Box 2718",
            "city":"Frisco",
            "state":"Colorado",
            "zipCode":"80443",
            "country":"United States",
            "phone":"(970) 262-3515",
            "fax":"(970) 668-9431",
            "latlon":"39.5754576,-106.0952117",
            "distance":16.8,
            "countryCode":"US",
            "HSA":[

            ],
            "id":"001i000001XR9dqAAD_0",
            "type":"partnerLocation",
            "contentType":"child"
         },
         {
            "locationType":"Primary Location",
            "addressLine1":"117 S 6th Ave.,",
            "city":"Frisco",
            "state":"Colorado",
            "zipCode":"80443",
            "country":"United States",
            "phone":"+1.970.262.3515",
            "latlon":"39.5754576,-106.0952117",
            "distance":16.8,
            "countryCode":"US",
            "HSA":[

            ],
            "id":"001i000001XR9dqAAD_1",
            "type":"partnerLocation",
            "contentType":"child"
         },
         {
            "locationType":"Address",
            "addressLine1":"RESORTINTERNET\r2718:FRISCO:80443\r117 S 6TH AVERM UNIT 2",
            "city":"Frisco",
            "state":"Colorado",
            "stateCode":"CO",
            "zipCode":"80443",
            "country":"United States",
            "latlon":"39.5744309,-106.0975203",
            "distance":16.9,
            "countryCode":"US",
            "HSA":[

            ],
            "id":"001i000001XR9dqAAD_100",
            "type":"partnerLocation",
            "contentType":"child"
         }
      ],
      "verticalHierarchyWraps":[

      ],
      "primaryLocation":{
         "locationType":"Headquarters",
         "addressLine1":"117 S 6th Ave.,",
         "addressLine2":"PO Box 2718",
         "city":"Frisco",
         "state":"Colorado",
         "zipCode":"80443",
         "country":"United States",
         "phone":"(970) 262-3515",
         "fax":"(970) 668-9431",
         "latlon":"39.5754576,-106.0952117",
         "distance":16.8,
         "countryCode":"US"
      }
   }
];
 for (var index in data)
 {
   
   var item=data[index];
   console.log(item["name"]);
   console.log(item);

 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Alexander Higgins. It didn't work out.  I'm getting this error now: "list indices must be integers or slices, not dict"